# Call Windows API from node.js msg

Tags: javascript, node.js, winapi

I am new at Node, I have this simple Node.js server works on windows

Server Code

```
var ws = require("websocket-server");

var server = ws.createServer();

server.addListener("connection", function(client){
    console.log("new connection");
    client.send("aaaaaa");
    client.addListener("message", function(msg){
        console.log(msg);
    });
});

server.listen(8080);
```

I just want to call windows API insted of line

```
console.log(msg);
```

is there any way to do this without using external library

any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think [node-ffi](https://github.com/rbranson/node-ffi) can help you to do that. `node-ffi` provides functionality for loading and calling dynamic libraries. With `node-ffi` you can get access to `user32` (for example) lib and call their functions from node.js.

```
var FFI = require('node-ffi');

function TEXT(text){
   return new Buffer(text, 'ucs2').toString('binary');
}

var user32 = new FFI.Library('user32', {
   'MessageBoxW': [
      'int32', [ 'int32', 'string', 'string', 'int32' ]
   ]
});

var OK_or_Cancel = user32.MessageBoxW(
   0, TEXT('I am Node.JS!'), TEXT('Hello, World!'), 1
);
```

Comment: thanks i have tried it, unfortunately doesn't working 
'npm install node-ffi' not working for me, so i have asked if there is any solution without using external library

Comment: As far as i know node-ffi requires python to be installed on your system. Node.js don't have native methods to calling winapi functions.

Comment: I have installed it but there is configuration errors :

gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\ProgramFiles\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:415:16)


and so ...

Comment: Also you need to install `node-gyp` with requirements. Look at this installation instructions: https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp#installation

Comment: Worked for me! Though note that the module's been renamed to just "ffi".

Answer (score 10):

I didn't want to edit @Vadim's answer because it is accepted, but I think the package has been renamed to just '[ffi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffi)'.  This worked for me:

```
npm install -s ffi
```

And using @Vadim's source but changing the package name to `ffi`:

```
var FFI = require('ffi');

function TEXT(text){
   return new Buffer(text, 'ucs2').toString('binary');
}

var user32 = new FFI.Library('user32', {
   'MessageBoxW': [
      'int32', [ 'int32', 'string', 'string', 'int32' ]
   ]
});

var OK_or_Cancel = user32.MessageBoxW(
   0, TEXT('I am Node.JS!'), TEXT('Hello, World!'), 1
);
```

Comment: This answer is excellent but the buffer api has deprecated using new like this, and also you need a trailing null for c style strings. Code: "function TEXT(text) { return Buffer.from(text + '\0', 'ucs2')}"

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this NPM package which already has (much of) the Win32 API entered (using ffi) and ready to use from NodeJS: https://github.com/waitingsong/node-win32-api

Comment: Just giving my two cents, I would not use such library as it not being used by a lot of projects (looking at the NPM stats) the development may stop at any moment leaving you with an outdated library.