# Node JS: How to Create Window? (without HTML)

Tags: node.js

I will create a program that can be managed by window GUI but I can't find any package or code to do that without HTML. I want it to work on computers that doesn't have a browser etc. So I want the window like `tkinter` in Python. But in Node JS. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775201/call-windows-api-from-node-js-msg

Comment: tkinter is a *library*, which interfaces to whatever GUI the OS provides: XLib for Linux, Win32 for Windows, etc.  You'll need to find a similar library for NodeJS for your particular platform.

Comment: Can I create GUI's with `win32-api` library? But not message box, like Chrome or Skype window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of libraries to make GUIs in node. Your choice depends on what OSs your application should run on.

If you want something that works in Linux then https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gtk is pretty good.

For windows, there is https://www.npmjs.com/package/win32-api

I dont know much about macOS but I recon you might be able to get GTK running.

If you dont mind a heavy runtime and want cross-platform support [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) or [NW.js](https://nwjs.io/) might be a good pick

Comment: I want for Windows. Is there any package or anything for Windows?

Comment: You could design a window with the win32 apis that i have linked to.

Comment: The examples are in TypeScript language. Is there any code that in JavaScript language?

Comment: The examples on the NPM page of win32-api are all normal ES6 JS

Comment: See full example of window creation at https://github.com/waitingsong/node-win32-api/blob/master/packages/win32-api/demo/create_window.ts .